# Qooxdoo reuse cookies between sessions?

Tags: cookies, selenium, selenium-webdriver, qooxdoo

Recently I have create some UI tests for a qooxdoo application with the built-in simulator ( I am using qooxdoo 3.0.1, selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0 and firefox23) 
and I need to store a cookie in the browser and save that for the next time that it open.

code that stores the cookie:

```
 if(!this.getQxSelenium().isCookiePresent(debugVariable))
      this.getQxSelenium().createCookie("debugVariable=0","path=/, max_age=350000, domain=subdomain.foo.com");
console.log(this.getQxSelenium().getCookieByName("debugVariable"));
```

I have find that there is an argument in the server the -profilesLocation that specifies the directory that holds the Firefox profiles that java clients can use to start up the Firefox 
I even try to use -browserSessionReuse but it does not working either for me.

I see this is not enough what other solution I could try to make the Firefox to remember the cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a qooxdoo-specific issue. I tried it with a plain HTML+JS page and Selenium's -firefoxProfileTemplate option and it didn't keep the cookie either.

You could try using an older version of Selenium (and perhaps also Firefox). -firefoxProfileTemplate is specific to Selenium RC, which is deprecated and gets more broken with every new release.